# Save file in device internal storage using path_provider : flutter

Tags: flutter, file, sharedpreferences, path-provider

I want to save file in Device internal storage **`Android/Ios`** with [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider). am saving file to storage with SharedPreferences if I am wring static path like `/storage/emulated/0/Documents` this will work on some device but not work higher version. If the file is saved using `path_provider` where to see this saved file?

Getting Path:

```
Future<String> get filePath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory.path;
}
```

Save file to device storage:

```
final directory = await filePath;//directory path
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
sharedPreferences.setString(
          'Key', DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
      print('Save file to device storage');
      File filePathName = File("$directory/api_json_file.txt");
      print('Save Dir- $filePathName');
      await filePathName.writeAsString(sharedPreferences.getString('Key').toString());
```